# react redux mapStateToProps round brackets

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Why `mapStateToProps` has these round `()` brackets around props object ?
Is that an IIFE or something like that ?

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  auth: state.auth
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regular function expression or function declaration has a *block statement* part as a function body:

To better understand the subject lets first check our definitions:

[Statements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements):

> JavaScript applications consist of statements with an appropriate syntax. A single statement may span multiple lines. Multiple statements may occur on a single line if each statement is separated by a semicolon. This isn't a keyword, but a group of keywords.

Example:

```
x && y;
x + y;
x,y;
while(something) {}
if (whatever) {}
```

[Block statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block)

> A block statement (or compound statement in other languages) is used to group zero or more statements. The block is delimited by a pair of curly brackets and may optionally be labelled

Example:

```
const y = 1;

{
   y();
   const y = 2;
   if (x) {
     console.log(x);
   }
}
```

Some statements can be [labelled](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label):

> The labeled statement can be used with break or continue statements. It is prefixing a statement with an identifier which you can refer to.

Example:

```
var str = "";

loop1:
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  if (i === 1) {
    continue loop1;
  }
  str = str + i;
}

console.log(str);
// expected output: "0234"
```

but can also be

```
x: 1 // just a global level labelled statement

x: { // labelled statement with a block statement body
    y: { // labelled statement with a block statement body
       z: 1 // labelled statement with an expression statement
            // containing numeric literal expression
       ...
    }
}
```

Arrow function allows to write an expression statement instead of a block statement as its body. This is one of the reasons why it's different from regular functions and why it's so favoured.

Now for the purpose of the example let's imaging we try:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  auth: state.auth
};
```

when you use `{}` here you might not mean block statement, you might mean [object literal expression](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#prod-ObjectLiteral) `{a: 1, b: 2}` with property keys and values.

But the js compiler sees a statement, which happens to be a block statement, thus parses everything within it as statements, that's why 
your `auth: state.auth` is parsed as a *labelled statement*.

Now when compiler sees this:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  auth: state.auth
});
```

or

```
const mapStateToProps = state => state;
```

or

```
const mapStateToProps = state => 1;
```

or anything except block statement you name it, it's trying to treat the following as an expression statement.

And arrow function is returning whatever that expression is returning , so for example in

```
x = () => a = 1
```

`a = 1` part is treated as an assignment expression, which on it's own returns 1.

As of the [grouping operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Grouping) `()`, it treats its
operand as an expression and returns its evaluation result as outlined [here](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-grouping-operator-runtime-semantics-evaluation)

> ParenthesizedExpression:(Expression)
>   Return the result of evaluating Expression. This may be of type Reference.

Thus our `({
  auth: state.auth
})` is compiled as an object literal expression which after evaluation returns the underlying object to whoever calls `mapStateToProps`.

Hope this clarifies it a bit.

Comment: As they evolve JS further and further, it looks like somebody took a few languages (C, Python, Java...) and a bunch of ideas (dictionaries, functional programming paradigms,...), thew it in a blender, and figured the world would produce more than enough junior programmers to sort through the garbled syntax and ideas that became the soup.  What a mess.

Comment: @eSurfsnake well that's the price you pay when you design an immensely powerful and flexible dynamic language. It's just complicated, like Java, like C++. But it's a standalone solution on the same level as the aforementioned languages, a lot of brilliant minds tirelessly work to make it even better and imho and as per last spec editions they have very much succeeded.

Comment: I think it is s stretch to say someone is 'designing' an immensely powerful and flexible language.  It's pretty clear the initial language was a hack, and stuff just keeps getting added on top of the old layers of paint.  Languages like Lisp, Haskell, and C clearly had a design in mind that was thought out up-front; JS is Darwinian evolution run amok - hence the need for so many libraries and pre-processors.

Answer (score 2):

In arrow function you can return some value by not using `{}` brackets like this

```
const mapStateToProps = state => state;
```

This means `mapStateToProps` will return `state`.

And if you want to return an object from that function then you need to wrap that object in `()` brackets. That way it knows that it is returning an object instead of creating a function definition.

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  auth: state.auth
});
```

So in above code, `mapStateToProps` will return an object (i.e. `{ auth: ..}`)

See more info [Returning object literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Returning_object_literals)

Answer (score 1):

It is a simple construct to instruct whatever comes inside () is implicitly returned.

It is not an IIFE

Comment: `If you are specifying it in one line, what comes after fat arrow is implicitly returned` Nope. It will return `undefined`.

Comment: You are true. Editing it